# Listen to a microphone remotely

Tags: windows, audio, remote, microphone

Is there a way to listen remotely to a microphone located on a another computer?

I don't want to do a remote desktop connection with sound support, nor to connect to a webcam using some client (Java, Flash, ...). Only the sound should be sent from the remote PC to my local PC?

Any idea for such a tool? It should run on Windows: server side on Windows 7, client side on various Windows (mostly XP).

Comment: Maybe use Winamp or VLC to stream audio? How much control do you have over the remote computer?

Comment: @Ivo: full control, it's my computer, no hidden spying here.

Comment: I meant more like: is the server side computer locked down, hidden away, very very remote. This would be a nice setup to make a computer act as a babyphone ;-)

Comment: Be aware that this activity may be illegal in your area.  Check your surveillance laws.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [this page on VLC remote](http://www.autopoetic.com/vlcremote/)

[image]

Their program let's you control VLC over a network.

[In regular VLC](http://www.iupui.edu/~nmstream/live/howtovlc.html) you can go to the File menu, choose Open Capture Device. Under the Direct Show tab, select the Audio Device Name from the drop down menu. Your device should show up in this menu. If not, check your microphone connection or click the Refresh List button.

Also check out [this Engadget article](http://www.engadget.com/2005/11/29/how-to-stream-almost-anything-using-vlc/) on streaming with VLC, there's even a web-interface

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Skype](http://www.skype.com/).

> Add your friends as contacts, then call, video call and instant message with them for free.

Comment: Is it possible to auto-answer a call?

Comment: @Snark - apparently so: http://getsatisfaction.com/skype/topics/how_can_i_get_skype_to_auto_answer_my_calls

Comment: Though the fact that this plugin exists to do just that suggests it might not work out of the box: http://code.google.com/p/skypeautoanswer/

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be connected to another PC? A Bluetooth microphone would work from another room.

Comment: The 2 computers are 80 miles away. Slightly too far for Bluetooth :-) .

Comment: :) ha, that just made my day...

Comment: That just means you need more RF Power!