# How to stream my voice over the web?

Tags: windows, streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Live Video on website, conferencing](https://superuser.com/questions/85946/live-video-on-website-conferencing)

Hi, I want to stream my voice over the web (embedded in HTML), how I can do?

I don't want to use an hosted solution, as I have a dedicated server with lots of bandwidth

I was thinking to use edcast+icecast to stream my voice, and then, how to embed in a webpage?
A flash MP3 player?

The client and the server are both Windows-based

Comment: stream voice it's not the same as stream video...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll admit I don't know, but if I wanted to do this I would start by investigating [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). And if you don't want to do a full install to play around, try [VLC Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable) which I think has full capabilities.

[image]

Comment: I suggested a similar solution here: http://superuser.com/questions/103698/listen-to-a-microphone-remotely/103705#103705 so it definitely works

Comment: Great catch on that how to article. I have been looking for something like that just in case I ever wanted to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp). It's free and simple to set up.  It includes a server.  It's intended to stream music, but would probably serve your needs well.